# Question about initial forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, graded-modules

I am working through Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*, and in Chapter $5$ he defines the following map. Say we have a filtration of modules ${\cal F}:M=M_0\supset M_1\supset\cdots$. Then for $f\in M$, let $n$ be the greatest natural number so that $f\in M_n$. He defines $\operatorname{in}(f)=f\pmod {M_{n+1}}\in M_n/M_{n+1}$ (and if $f$ is in all $M_i$ then define $\operatorname{in}(f)=0$).

I am trying to prove some properties of the map for my homework, but I am trying to make sense of the expression: $\operatorname{in}(f)+\operatorname{in}(g)$, because these two terms are in different sets, e.g. how can we add $x\in M_1/M_2$ with $y\in M_4/M_5$?

Comment: $\operatorname{gr}_{\mathcal F}(M)$ is an abelian group with respect to the addition on each component. In your case $x+y=(0,x,0,0,y,0,\dots)$.

Comment: @YACP It seems like $in(f+g)=in(f)+in(g)$ would be homogeneous (only one non-zero component) on the rhs, but on the lhs it would have two non-zero components.